# Comparing values in different columns with same id tag

Tags: excel-formula

I have an excel sheet containing a list of IDs each one of which has a few different values associated with it in other columns. For example, one id will have a 5 under a Height tab, and a 120 under a weight tab. Some ids get repeated twice and I want to have a formula which can compare the second id to the first one in each of the categories and return the difference between the two of them. For example if my chart is:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0QI6.jpg)

I want to compare the height and weight of row 1 and 3 and return -1 and -20 to store in new columns. Is there a way of easily doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a few ways you could approach this. My suggested approach would be to use the following (formulas entered using `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`):

`Height_Diff: ={MIN(IF(A$2:A$4=A2,B$2:B$4))-MAX(IF(A$2:A$4=A2,B$2:B$4))}`

`Weight_Diff: ={MIN(IF(A$2:A$4=A2,C$2:C$4))-MAX(IF(A$2:A$4=A2,C$2:C$4))}`

This would result in the following table:

```
+----+--------+--------+-------------+-------------+
| id | Height | Weight | Height_Diff | Weight_Diff |
+----+--------+--------+-------------+-------------+
|  1 |      5 |    100 |          -1 |         -20 |
|  2 |      4 |    123 |           0 |           0 |
|  1 |      4 |     80 |          -1 |         -20 |
+----+--------+--------+-------------+-------------+
```